# Java - Getting error "Socket is closed" when my Client class connects on my Server class

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, parallel-processing

I made two classes in Java named Server.java and Client.java. The Server is listening to a port and is waiting for a Client to connect (using sockets). When the client connects he can type a pair of numbers separated by "space" and if that pair exists in my *edge_list.txt* file the Server returns "1" to the client, if not it returns "0". After I completed my initial project I wanted to also use **Threads** so that it can handle multiple users at once, but when the Client connects I get -> **java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed**.

I reviewed my code and try using **flush()** instead of **close()**. Also, I thought I was closing the socket before the user can read the file, but it didn't seem that was the case. Below I will have the **Server.java** code block and not the **Client.java**, cause it doesn't seem to be the problem.

## Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server {
    private static final int PORT = 9999;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + PORT);

            while (true) {
                try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()) {
                    System.out.println("Client connected: " + socket);
                    new ClientHandler(socket).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class ClientHandler extends Thread {
        private Socket socket;
        ClientHandler(Socket socket){
            this.socket = socket;
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                //Creating Sockets and Streams
                InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(output));

                while (socket.isConnected() && !socket.isClosed()) {
                    //Reading what the Client types
                    String request = reader.readLine();
                    //Split the values with "space" and store them in an array,
                    //then parse those values to two integers
                    String[] values = request.split(" ");
                    int A = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
                    int B = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
                    //Check if the pair in the file exists using checkPairInFile() method
                    boolean exists = checkPairInFile(A, B);
                    //if it does print 1 else 0
                    writer.println(exists ? "1" : "0");
                    //Flush the output to send the response back to the client
                    writer.flush();
                }

                //Print the disconnected user
                System.out.println("Client disconnected: " + socket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }



    private static boolean checkPairInFile(int A, int B) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("edge_list.txt"))) {
            //Scanning the file lines
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                //Split the values with "space"
                String[] values = line.split(" ");
                //Parse the values from String -> Int
                int a = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
                //if both exist return true
                if (A == a && B == b) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

P.S. Thanks in advance for your help, in case this is problem with my Client.java file I will update the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part:

```
try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()) {
    System.out.println("Client connected: " + socket);
    new ClientHandler(socket).start();
}
```

accepts a socket, then prints a message, then starts a new thread, then closes the socket. At some point later the new thread finishes starting up and tries to use the socket and realizes it was already closed.

`try (...) {...}` (officially called *try-with-resources*) always closes the things when it gets to the `}`. That's the point of it. If you don't want to close the socket at the `}` then you shouldn't use this type of statement.

Comment: I never knew try-catch closed sockets opened! Thats interesting, and I’ll keep it in mind.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b that's the whole point of the try(){} as opposed to just try{}

Comment: @user253751 That seems to the fix. I thought try-with-recourses would close the socket when the user is done. Thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: @user253751 That makes sense now, I never even knew about the try() {} catch{} in the first place. But it seems like something I will use in the future if needed!

Comment: See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in the Java documentation.